# ImageURL on c# code not showing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, visual-studio-2010

I have image on aspx page as:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgOrgLogo" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="35px" AlternateText="Image Not Found"  />
```

I have ready path for it in database, and I am fetching image name from database and setting up its path as:

```
 string path = obj.ExecuteScalar(sql);   
 imgOrgLogo.ImageUrl = "/OrgImages/" + path;
 imgOrgLogo.DataBind();
```

from string path I get the image name.

I checked folder OrgImages contains specified image.

But image is not viewing after running this code.

When i done inspect element from browser its showing:

```
   <img id="MainContent_imgOrgLogo" src="" alt="Image Not Found"

  style="height:35px;width:50px;">
```

Path is not getting settled.

What is wrong in my code??

Please help me.

Comment: during which event are you setting the ImageUrl property?

Comment: ddlOrganization_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Have a look at the produced HTML code in a browser. How does the src attribute look like?

Comment: as i shown above sir : <img id="MainContent_imgOrgLogo" src="" alt="Image Not Found" style="height:35px;width:50px;">  src is blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<img id="MainContent_imgOrgLogo" src="" alt="Image Not Found" style="height:35px;width:50px;" runat="server" />
```

I added `runat="server"` so you can access the `<img ID` in codebehind and set the `src`.

Example: `MainContent_imgOrgLogo.Src = (YOUR IMAGEPATH)`

Or try (since you are talking about a `ddlOrganization_SelectedIndexChanged`):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    string path = obj.ExecuteScalar(sql);   
    imgOrgLogo.ImageUrl = "/OrgImages/" + path;
    imgOrgLogo.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit:**

*but on selection it should change the image.*

If you want to achieve that, you should put the `<img`-attribute inside a `UpdatePanel` and on the `ddlOrganization_SelectedIndexChanged`-event you should paste your `.ImageURL`-code.

Comment: but on selection it should change the image...in this case it will not

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
imgOrgLogo.ImageUrl = "/OrgImages/" + path;
```

with

```
imgOrgLogo.ImageUrl = "~/OrgImages/" + path;
```

and remove

```
imgOrgLogo.DataBind();
```

Comment: show me the html of href attribute of image generated by browser

Comment: <img id="MainContent_imgOrgLogo" src="" alt="Image Not Found" style="height:35px;width:50px;">

Comment: well your ImageUrl attribute may be ovride by other code in your code behind.

Comment: remove imgOrgLogo.DataBind(); it will work with out updatepanel