# fetch imagepath from database and display in image control in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to fetch the imagepath of an image  from the database and display it in an image control but the images are not being displayed. I tried :

```
public void FetchQimage()
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select image_path from Questionimage where sub_code = '" + Session["subject"] + "' ", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        // {

        Image3.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[0]["image_path"].ToString();
    }
}
```

The image path is in the format : D:\Project\projectxyz\image

Comment: might be something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683296/imageurl-on-c-sharp-code-not-showing-image

Comment: If the root folder of the website is `projectxyz`, then you need to store `\image`. The website cannot browse above it's own root folder for security reasons.

Comment: do you mean to say i need to store the images within the project? But there are many images  so i wanted them to be accesses from the system.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you cannot get to them with `src=`. If they are outside you need a Generic Handler that loads the image from outside the root folder and serves it as a stream or base64.

Comment: And on a separate note: Parametarize your queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: thank you. im trying this :http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/08/display-image-from-database-byte-array-in-image-control-without-using-generic-handler-in-aspnet.html

Comment: Then you are storing the images in the DB. That could also work. Then you should also look into `SQL FileStream`.

Comment: Are you looking for `Server.MapPath()`?